# Angular Service worker Offline showing errors

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

I am following this [angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) for service workers and have done it verbatim, at least 6 times.

I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5YtNQJQu31Y as well as this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=othhfZ0mGjU&t=464s to see if there are any variations maybe.

Everything works well, however when I go offline and refresh I get the errors in the below image.

I have searched all over the web but can't work out why this would happen.

As you can see I have the images and fonts loading in nicely offline, so its doing its job, those items are in my config but why there be the errors for manifest.webmanifest?

I am using http-server on the dist for testing.

Why would it partially work?

I have googled *504 gateway timeout (from serviceworker) angular* but I cant make sense of it. I am probably missing something obvious as I have been staring at this for ages.

Any help is appreciated.

I have this as my ngsw-config.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ],
        "urls": [
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500",
          "https://fonts.gstatic.com/**"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: when I look at [this tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#simulating-a-network-issue) from what I've achieved reading the manifest is not supposed to be cached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at the tutorials you've pointed out I can't see manifest files.
I would try adding:

```
"/*.webmanifest"
```

to your list of accepted files

one other solution comes from [this website](https://dev.to/ronakpatel70/creating-pwa-using-angular-7-step-by-step-guide-1mb3)

where you need to add in `angular.json` under property `assets` the reference to your file and also add as a `<link>` tag reference to your manifest file

Comment: Thank you for this, I did as you said and it worked. This pointed me in the right direction.